# Sort after rollup preserving totals and subtotals rows position

Tags: mysql

This is a sample result from a mysql with rollup

```
|country | region | value  |
|--------|--------|--------|
|   us   |  west  |   5    |
|   us   |  east  |   15   |
|   us   |  north |   10   |
|   us   |  total |   30   |
|   uk   |  west  |   3    |
|   uk   |  east  |   2    |
|   uk   |  north |   1    |
|   uk   |  total |   6    |
|  total |  total |   36   |
```

i would like to sort the value column like this preserving the totals rows position

ASC

```
|   us   |  west  |   5    |
|   us   |  north |   10   |
|   us   |  east  |   15   |
|   us   |  total |   30   |
|   uk   |  north |   1    |
|   uk   |  east  |   2    |
|   uk   |  west  |   3    |
|   uk   |  total |   6    |
|  total |  total |   36   |
```

DESC

```
|   us   |  east  |   15   |
|   us   |  north |   10   |
|   us   |  west  |   5    |
|   us   |  total |   30   |
|   uk   |  west  |   3    |
|   uk   |  east  |   2    |
|   uk   |  north |   1    |
|   uk   |  total |   6    |
|  total |  total |   36   |
```

this is a query sample :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
  COALESCE(country, 'total') AS country, 
  COALESCE(region, 'total' ) AS region, 
  SUM('value'), 
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY country ASC, region ASC 
  WITH ROLLUP
) t
ORDER BY ... maybe something to do here ...
```

maybe a sort order based on regex ?
or using a mysql string function ?

i don't know how to resolve my problem

thank by advance for help

...

with your help and after some personal reflection
i think i have a nice way to do this now

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT 
   IF(IFNULL(country, 1),'total',NULL) AS country,
   IF(IFNULL(region, 1),'total',NULL) AS region,
   COALESCE(country, 'Total') AS country1, 
   COALESCE(region, 'Total') AS region1, 
   SUM(value) as `value to sort`
   FROM data_table
   GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP
) t 
ORDER BY  
country IS NULL DESC, 
country1 ASC, 
region IS NULL DESC, ...

 ... `value to sort` DESC

(or)

 ... `value to sort` ASC
```

i have now totals and sub totals always after aggregates and sub aggregates values even using DESC sort :-)

do you think it's a good way ?
it's working for me in all cases

Answer (score 4):

Based on the original version of [Johan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673236/sort-after-rollup-preserving-totals-and-subtotals-rows-position/7673771#7673771):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(country, 'total') AS country,
    COALESCE(region, 'total' ) AS region,
    SUM(`value`) as `value`, 
  FROM `table` 
  GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP
) t
ORDER BY country = 'total', country, region = 'total', `value`
```

The way this trick works is that the expression `country = 'total'` evaluates to 1 (true) if the `country` column equals `'total'`, and to 0 (false) otherwise. In ascending numerical order, 1 comes after 0.  Thus, sorting by that expression forces any rows where the `country` column equals `'total'` to sort after any other columns.

Similarly, sorting by the expressions `region = 'total'` before `value` forces any rows with the value `'total'` in their `region` to sort after any other rows with the same `country`, regardless of their `value` column.

The same trick works with other [comparison operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html) too.  For example, if you wanted to force negative values to sort after positive values, you could sort the rows by `` `value` < 0, `value` ``.

Comment: Thanks, this is the best replacement for deprecated sorting that I've found yet. It's a shame they've removed it, without a proper alternative. Btw, didn't find that you can explicitly specify order for some values with `=` as you did here on official documentation. + for that,

Comment: @DanM: The way this trick works is that the expressions `country = 'total'` evaluates to 1 (true) if the `country` column equals `'total'`, and to 0 (false) otherwise. In ascending numerical order, 1 comes after 0. Thus, sorting by a comparison operator forces any rows for which the comparison is true to sort after any rows for which it is false (or before them, if you sort in descending order).

Comment: Thanks! That's clever!

Answer (score 1):

The grand total line that `with rollup` produces has all nul values for the non-aggregate rows.
You can exploit this to force that row to be last (or first).

Try this, haven't tested it so I'm not 100% sure:

```
SELECT 
  ti2.country
  , ti2.region
  ,ti2.`value`
FROM table1 to1
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
              t2.country
              ,IFNULL(ti1.region,'subtotal') as country
              ,ti1.`value` 
            FROM (
             SELECT 
              t1.country
              , t1.region
              , SUM(t1.`value`) as `value`
             FROM table1 t1
             WHERE t1.country = to1.country 
             GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP) ti1 ) ti2
ON (ti2.country = to1.country)
GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY country, region = 'subtotal', region
```

Note that order by clauses should go into the outer(!) select, not in an inner select.
*(I know order by in inner selects works most of the time, but when the query gets complicated it can mess up and sent you off track)*
Also note that it's not a great idea to rely on the non-standard implicit order by behavior build into MySQL's `group by` clause; best to stick to standard SQL unless there is a clear benefit to be gained.

Comment: i would like to sort on values, i don't see where country1 and region1 are used. i need to keep totals at the bottom of each country, not all totals at the end of the table

Comment: `with rollup` only produces **one** grand total, not multiple grand totals.

Comment: I think you were very close with your original answer.  I've posted a solution based on it below.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky one this! I've made a (rather large) assumption that you have a countryId column available to use in your source table that uniquely identifies each country in the table (so 'us' has countryId=1, 'uk' has countryId =2 etc etc). If you don't you could always add one:

```
-- Descending
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
  COALESCE(country, 'total') AS pays,
  COALESCE(region, 'total' ) AS region,
  SUM(value) as value, 
  (SUM(value) * (CASE WHEN COALESCE(region, 'total') = 'total' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END)   
    + countryId*(SELECT SUM(value) FROM test_table) 
    + CASE WHEN COALESCE(country, 'total') = 'total' 
           THEN (SELECT SUM(value) FROM test_table) ELSE 0 END) as rank1
  FROM test_table 
  GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP
) t
ORDER BY rank1 asc;


-- Ascending
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
  COALESCE(country, 'total') AS pays, 
  COALESCE(region, 'total' ) AS region,
  SUM(value) as value, 
  (SUM(value) + countryId*(SELECT SUM(value) FROM test_table) 
    + CASE WHEN COALESCE(country, 'total') = 'total' 
           THEN (SELECT SUM(value) FROM test_table) ELSE 0 END) as rank1
  FROM table 
  GROUP BY country, region WITH ROLLUP
) t
order by rank1 asc;
```

Not the prettiest and certainly not the cleanest but should help you out.