# MySQL groupby with rollup and orderby based on aggregated column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a group by of the amount by each customer_id with 'Total' amount at the end using rollup

```
select ifnull(customer_id,'Total') as 'Customer_id'
 ,sum(amount) as 'Amount' 
  from payment 
 group 
    by customer_id with rollup 
 order 
    by customer_id = 'Total'
 , sum(amount) desc;
```

I have tried using customer_id = 'Total' as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673236/sort-after-rollup-preserving-totals-and-subtotals-rows-position) but it didn't help.

I want to sort the data in ascending order based on the sum(amount) value but the 'Total' of all the columns should be the last one.

| Customer_id | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Total | 65819.36 |
| 15 | 134.68 |
| 16 | 120.71 |
| 17 | 98.79 |
| 18 | 91.78 |
| 19 | 125.76 |
| 20 | 115.70 |
| 21 | 155.65 |
| 22 | 113.78 |
| 23 | 119.70 |

Comment: it seems to work well https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0694193fbfb28b245d4e983a13deb8da

Comment: @nbk the op states that they want the total last, your demo has the total first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't help that you're using `customer_id` as an alias as well as it being a column in your table.

Are you ***sure*** the `ORDER BY` is checking that column name after the `ifnull()`?   Maybe it's checking the `customer_id` from the table, not your calculation?  It's ambiguous.

To make things unambiguous, always refer to a column in a source table...

```
ORDER BY
    payment.customer_id IS NULL,
    SUM(payment.amount) DESC
```

Even better, use the function `GROUPING()` as per the manual...

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_grouping

So...

```
ORDER BY
    GROUPING(payment.customer_id),
    SUM(payment.amount) DESC
```

This is able to tell the difference between a `NULL` (or `'TOTAL'`) just happening to appear in the data, as opposed to the `ROLLUP` actually grouping up a column.